# How to get Kohana base_url in template

Tags: php, templates, kohana, base-url

In **Kohana 3** `bootstrap.php` one can define `base_url`:

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/foo/',
));
```

This usually means also moving the `/js/`, `/css/` and other media to that base dir like `/foo/js/`, `/foo/css/`. My question is not to discuss good or bad of such.

Is there a *built-in* way in Kohana to access the **base_url** from a *template* (just like in *Django* you can use `{{ MEDIA_URL }}css/`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can output the base url as using [`URL::base`](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api/URL#base):

```
<?php echo URL::base(); ?>
```

If you're outputting a url relative to that you probably want [`URL::site`](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api/URL#site):

```
<?php echo URL::site('css/'); ?>
```

Kohana 3 template controllers use the View class to render templates.
Views are normal php files and have no special syntax, so just use the normal `<?php ... ?>` tags as above.
The View class allows you to declare variables for use in that view, before you render it.

Comment: My site is placed in the domain root and the `/index.php/` URL part is hidden (the well known way). `URL::base()` gives `/` and `URL::site()` gives `/index.php/` - these are of little use, I'd say...

Comment: I have found that `URL::site('myfolder', 'http');` does almost what I need but it still adds `/index.php/` which brakes everything. What I need would liik like `http://example.com/myfolder/` but it gives me `http://example.com/index.php/myfolder/`

Comment: This is due to your configuration of the 'index_file' option in your application configuration/bootstrap. See: http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/tutorials/clean-urls

Answer (score 2):

One good way is that in your layout view, in the head of the HTML you put near the `<title>` tag:

```
<base href="<?php echo URL::base(TRUE) ?>">
```

and then, you load your assets this way:

```
<img src="assets/images/img.jpg" alt="">
```

The HTML `<base>` tag is a way of defining a base URL for all the assets in the page. This way you load your image located at `/foo/assets/images/img.jpg` without making a `URL::base()` call in every tag. I hope it helps.